# Angular 12+ : getting errors after applying ssr steps

Tags: angular, seo, server-side-rendering, angular-universal, angular-seo

I have existing angular project. I need to apply ssr on my existing angular project. I am following [this](https://www.bacancytechnology.com/blog/server-side-rendering-with-angular-universal/)

1. `ng add @nguniversal/express-engine` this command works as expected.
2. `npm run dev:ssr` after running this command, and opening browser on given link, I am getting following errors

   **Could not find translation file**: ../../assets/translate/Pages/header/en.json

   **Could not find translation file**: ../../assets/translate/Pages/footer/en.json

   **Could not find translation file**: ../../assets/translate/Pages/home/en.json

   **ERROR ReferenceError: $ is not defined**
   at HeaderComponent.ngOnInit (mypro\dist\pro\server\main.js:228895:9)
   ....

   **ERROR ReferenceError: FormData is not defined**
   at HomeComponent.getUpcomingEvents (mypro\dist\pro\server\main.js:229576:29)
   ....

   **ERROR ReferenceError: localStorage is not defined**
   at AuthService.isLoggedIn (mypro\dist\pro\server\main.js:240521:9)
   ....

   **1 rules skipped due to selector errors:**
   .custom-file-input:lang(en)~.custom-file-label -> unmatched pseudo-class :lang

   **1 rules skipped due to selector errors:**
   .custom-file-input:lang(en)~.custom-file-label -> unmatched pseudo-class :lang

I have tried different ways but getting same errors each time. I am not getting what should I do to apply SSR on existing project. If I create new angular project and apply same steps it works but it does not works on existing project.

How should I remove these errors?

Please help and guide.

Answer (score 0):

`assets`: it sounds like you are using relative paths to retrieve translation files, give a try to absolute paths

`$` is more likely due to JQuery usage (that's a good opportunity to get rid of it)

`localstorage/FormData`: with SSR your app is rendered in a node environment, without a browser. The Web Storage/FormData API isn't available outside of a browser. You find related solutions on Google for localstorage depending on your usage (as there is no code in the question).
For Form data:

```
Install form-data via npm
npm install form-data

then import form-data to your component or service
import * as FormData from 'form-data';
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. formData error, localstorage , and $ I have resolved. now I am not getting how should I use absolute path in angular. could you pls tell me how I can get absolute path of those files which will be common for both local and production?

Answer (score 0):

You can give this article a try: [Angular Sevrer Side Rendering](https://writtenforcoders.com/blog/angular-universal-server-side-rendering-how-and-when-to-use-it)

It explains it in more detail and using the ng add command instead of npm commands